# how to create a mouse event with clientX and clientY defined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Dear all hoping that someone can give me a way to resolve or document this subject. I try to do something like that in one of my tests :
`const event = new window.MouseEvent('contextmenu',{clientX: 24,clientY: 42});`

I want to initialize x and y to verify that my contextual menu has good top and left values. In my code I'm using pageX and pageY ... and even if I replace the client with the page nothing happens.
In fact, I know how to initialize custom events with `{detail: value}` dictionary but for MouseEventInit dictionary I don't know the good structure?

I call the event like this: `await unit.dispatchEvent(event);` the await is only because I have some promise resolution inside the event function.

Comment: Sorry for my english. to be very clear the code is working for clientX and clientY.  I mean taht giving clientX in the dictionary, i'm able to console it in my eent function. But nothing works for pageX and pageY... it something to unit test. I'll have to use web driver to test that !!!!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)